# i want to create a light that cycles through all colours in the rgb range, how would i do so?

Tags: lighting

I want to make it cycle through colours to emulate an RGB led light, like a Philips hue, it's for a lamp I'm making which will be in a mockup room.

Comment: Just animate the colors for the emitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: light]

1. Select **HSL** color mode for interpolation.
2. Choose **Clockwise** method.
3. Select pure red color - **R: 1, G: 0, B: 0**.
4. Select pure red color and add a bit of blue - **R: 1, G: 0, B: 0.01**.
5. Animate **Factor** - press <kbd>I</kbd> over it to put keyframe on selected time frame.

[image: nodes]